# Parse WHERE clause in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I'm trying to parse WHERE clause of mysql query into an expression to get data from json file

For example:

```
`price`=8.95 AND `title`="The Lord price= AND of the Rings"
```

above example should be converted to the below string after replacing price and title value on left hand side

```
8.95==8.95 && 'The Lord price= AND of the Rings'=="The Lord price= AND of the Rings"
```

I have created one code ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pathan_siraj/e45oLy3r/4/)) to achieve this but this will break if I add AND ` in value as show below (it returns false if condition is not matching)

```
var obj = {price: 8.95, title: "'The Lord price= AND `of the Rings'"};
var whereString = '`price`=8.95 AND `title`="The Lord price= AND `of the Rings"';
```

So I wanted to understand is there any other better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first step split your `whereString` with [regex pattern](https://regexr.com/51sd2)

```
/(`[^`]+`=(?:"[^"]+"|\S+))(?:\s+AND\s+|$)/g
```

and store all `Group 1` matches.

In second step do substitutions for each match and finally merge all matches with string `AND`

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach, indifferent to the form the quoted string takes; split by `AND` outside of quotes, replace and join:

```js
let source = '`price`=8.95 AND `title`="The Lord price= AND of the Rings"';
let result = source
    .split(/\s*\bAND\b\s*(?![^`"]+")/)
    .map(s => s.replace(/`\w+`=(.*)/, '$1==$1'))
    .join(' && ');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```